# How to make the LED lights in my PC box in my Lenovo Ideacentre Y720 Cube desktop turn off?

Tags: windows-10, led

I want them off all the time even after restart, there's Lenovo Nerve Center but it turns them off only until a restart (the last time I checked)...

Comment: Can you check again?

Comment: Lenono Nerve Centre's latest update is on May 2016 so I guess the problem would still exist, I emailed Lenovo anyway...